# How to re-enable Windows user options pop-up for newly mounted USB Flash drives?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, autoplay

When insert new USB drive, a pop-up is displayed that gives option to view all files on drive. User also has option to suppress further messages.

So, this has been done... but now it must be un-done.

How can the pop-up (with the available user options for the external device) be re-enabled after having been suppressed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to:
`Control Panel` > `Hardware and Sounds` > `AutoPlay`

Or more simply, click on `Start` > Type `autoplay` and press `Enter`

Put a *check* on `Use AutoPlay for all media and devices` to make that AutoPlay *popup-dialog* appears for you again when you insert a *external media device*.

You might need to reboot your computer in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

When *Autoplay* system settings changes still do not work try the following to fix a corrupt registry and reset functionality:

*Applicable for Windows 7-10 - copy the following into an editor:*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDriveTypeAutoRun"=dword:00000091

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDriveTypeAutoRun"=-
```

and save it with the extension ".reg" (f.e. "autorun_restore_fix.reg") and run it - answer with yes. (Or run "Regedit" and edit the values in their proper keys as shown above). No need to reboot: changes to HKCU are immediate.

Hint: XP also can use the .reg file, just replace Registry Editor Version 5.00 with 4.00.

Alternatively, you can completely remove the following Explorer key from registry:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]`

...if there are no other values in it and you don't need specific users policies.
Don't worry: there is no "Explorer" sub-key at default Windows installation, so it's safe deleting it. This will make the USB autoplay action requester pop-up again as well, resetting it to defaults.